# How to replace multiple elements of vector based on a list of indices

Tags: clojure

With a ["a" "b" "r" "d" "r"] how does one replace items at indices 2 and 4 with a value say "mark" so that ["a" "b" "mark" "d" "mark"] is the result. The values of the candidate replacements are not known, just the indices are known.

Attempting to use `map` with the list `(2 4)` results in multiple vectors. `assoc` also does not work for an instance where there are multiple indices.

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just assoc new item to corresponding indices:

```
(assoc ["a" "b" "r" "d" "r"] 2 "mark" 4 "mark")
```

or make it more robust:

```
(apply assoc ["a" "b" "r" "d" "r"] (interleave [2 4] (repeat "mark")))
```

or with reduce:

```
(reduce #(assoc %1 %2 "mark")
        ["a" "b" "r" "d" "r"]
        [2 4])
```

Comment: The solution with `apply assoc` is both succinct and readable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Function definition:

```
(defn replace-indexed [smap coll]
  (map-indexed (fn [i e] (get smap i e)) coll))
```

Usage:

```
user> (replace-indexed {2 "mark" 4 "mark"} ["a" "b" "r" "d" "r"])
;; => ("a" "b" "mark" "d" "mark")
```

Result is a sequence, not a vector.

Comment: Much appreciated. I had attempted to map update-in with replace unsuccessfully.